# Linear gradient ends to early

Tags: css, webkit, linear-gradients

I have this linear gradient, and I can't figure out why it doesn't "work".

It is supposed to start in light gray and end in with, but about 80% in, it goes all white, with a notable white line. Can anyone see what is wrong?

My CSS is here:

```
background: white -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #efefef 0%,#f7f7f7 58%,#ffffff 100%);
background: white linear-gradient(left, #efefef 0%,#f7f7f7 58%,#ffffff 100%);
```

Thanks

Edit: I'm using chrome to test the gradient...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the default color white, use transparent...

```
background: transparent -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #efefef 0%,#f7f7f7 58%,#ffffff 100%);
background: transparent linear-gradient(left, #efefef 0%,#f7f7f7 58%,#ffffff 100%);
```

@JPuge Take a look here to make easy the CSS Gradients http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/